# Disable selected checkbox on button click

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

Just started working with the MVVM design pattern and I'm stuck.

When my application launches, I have a `treeview` populated with a list of objects names. I've setup the `IsChecked` Binding, and it works fine. I'm trying to setup the `IsEnabled` Binding.

I want the user to select the items in the treeview he wants, then click one of three buttons to perform an action. On click, I want the selected items to remain in the treeview, but be disabled, so the user cannot perform another action on those items.

I'm using a RelayCommand class in the application.

```
private ICommandOnExecute _execute;
private ICommandOnCanExecute _canExecute;

public RelayCommand(ICommandOnExecute onExecuteMethod, 
    ICommandOnCanExecute onCanExecuteMethod)
{
    _execute = onExecuteMethod;
    _canExecute = onCanExecuteMethod;
}

#region ICommand Members

public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
}

public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
{
    return _canExecute.Invoke(parameter);
}

public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    _execute.Invoke(parameter);
}

#endregion
```

My object model class uses this

```
private bool _isEnabled;
public bool IsEnabled
{
    get { return true; }
    set { _isEnabled = value};
}
```

Then within my button method I have

```
if (interfaceModel.IsChecked)
{
    //Does Something
    MyObjectName.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

And here is my xaml

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyObjectName}" Margin="5,2,1,2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
</CheckBox>
```

Comment: I think you are missing the implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged for the IsEnabled.

Comment: I think you may be on to something. Unlike the IsChecked property, I want the UI to be updated with the disable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a setup like this:

```
// Your ViewModel should implement INotifyPropertyChanged
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChnaged
{
    private bool _isEnabled;
    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get { return _isEnabled; }
        set 
        { 
             _isEnabled = value;
             SetPropertyChanged("IsEnabled");  // Add this to your setter.
        }
    }

    // This comes from INotifyPropertyChanged - the UI will listen to this event.
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void SetPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property) );
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `PropertyChanged` comes from having your ViewModel implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. To notify the UI, you have to raise that event, and tell it what property was changed (usually in the setter - see above).

Alternatively, if you don't like raw strings (I don't, personally), you can use generics and expression trees to do something like this:

```
public void SetPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T, Object>> onProperty) 
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null && onProperty.Body is MemberExpression) 
    {
        String propertyNameAsString = ((MemberExpression)onProperty.Body).Member.Name;
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyNameAsString));
    }
}
```

Where in your setter you can say:

```
public bool IsEnabled
{    
    set 
    { 
        _isEnabled = value;
        SetPropertyChanged<ViewModel>(x => x.IsEnabled);  
    }
}
```

And now it's strongly typed, which is kinda nice.

Comment: Like the strongly types...very nice!